# What exactly is the need of Back and Front poch delays in VGA ,TF,LCD Timings?

Tags: lcd, vga, tft

I am trying to interface a 24 Bit TFT screen.

But I am having a hard time understanding the need for Back and Front poch delays and how to calculate these ?

Comment: They're throwbacks to the days of CRTs.

Comment: If you could add some more details

Comment: If you need to decode a video waveform with the minimum number of vacuum tubes, these delays allow waveforms to settle to "black level" before and after the sync pulse while the scanning dot covers the screen "backwards", preventing ghosting and brightness variations in the picture. Not relevant to TFT screens, but there for compatibility with older systems.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanks for the detailed answer , So these delays are not required nowdays in TFT screens as these are controlled by very fast controllers.

Comment: You need to follow the timing diagram the manufacturer provides, regardless of the names of the waveform features, or your success will not be assured.

Comment: Distant memory - aren't some signals placed on some of the 'porches' for secondary uses?

Answer (score 1):

They are for compatibility with analog cathode-ray tube displays, so they are not really *needed*.

To compute them, use the algorithm specified in the [Coordinated Video Timings standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Video_Timings).
This algorithm is implemented in VESA's downloadable spreadsheet, and X.org's [cvt tool](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/tree/hw/xfree86/modes/xf86cvt.c).